# AS400 RPGLE unable to consume REST API with SSL

Tags: rest, ssl, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have successfully used IBM AxiscTransport API in AS400 (i 7.2) to consume REST API with HTTP. However, when there is SSL, my program fails with the following error.

*TransportFlush() call failed: 55:AxisTransportException: Cannot open a channel
to the remote end. Failed to open connection to server, the operation gsk_secure_soc_init() failed. GSKit Error is 410 - Peer not recognized or badly formatted message received.*

My sample source code:

```
uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

propBuf = 'GET' + X'00';                                                       
axiscTransportSetProperty(tHandle: AXISC_PROPERTY_HTTP_METHOD: %addr(propBuf));

propBuf = 'xx.xx.xx.xx' + X'00';                               
propInt = 80;                                                    
rc = axiscTransportSetProperty(tHandle:AXISC_PROPERTY_HTTP_PROXY:
                               %addr(propBuf):                   
                               %addr(propInt));                  

propBuf3 = 'true' + X'00';                                           
rc = axiscTransportSetProperty(tHandle: AXISC_PROPERTY_HTTP_PROXYSSL:
                                   %addr(propBuf3));                 

NONE = 'NONE' + X'00';                                               
propBuf = '/QIBM/USERDATA/ICSS/CERT/SERVER/DEFAULT.KDB' + X'00';     
propBuf3 = 'true' + X'00';                                           
rc = axiscTransportSetProperty(tHandle: AXISC_PROPERTY_HTTP_SSL:     
                               %addr(propBuf):                       
                               %addr(NULLSTR):%addr(NULLSTR):        
                               %addr(NONE):%addr(NONE):              
                               %addr(NONE):%addr(NONE):              
                               %addr(ENABLED):%addr(propBuf3):*NULL);

propBuf3 = 'true' + X'00';                                        
axiscTransportSetProperty(tHandle: AXISC_PROPERTY_CONVERT_PAYLOAD:
                          %addr(propBuf3));
```

I am stuck at this for months, and still unable to resolve it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could be your organization has a transparent proxy which intercepts SSL requests for you (for inspection to work)? Maybe you can talk to your security or network folks to help troubleshoot. I say this because HTTP works for you.

Comment: Shall check with the firewall team to investigate the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by doing this

pTolerate = 'true' + X'00';
pAppID    = 'API_MAN' + X'00';
axiscTransportSetProperty(t
Handle
                         :AXISC_PROPERTY_HTTP_SSL
                         :%addr(pKeyRingFile )
                         :%addr(pKeyRingSorP )
                         :%addr(pKeyRingLabel)
                         :%addr(pV2Cipher    )
                         :%addr(pV3Cipher    )
                         :%addr(pTLSCipher   )
                         :%addr(pTLSv11Cipher)
                         :%addr(pTLSv12Cipher)
                         :%addr(pTolerate    )
                         :%addr(pAppID       ));

The pAppID needs to be setup on the ISeries and the SSL certificate in the store linked to the Application ID. 
All other parameters were blanks.